# phpmailer is not send mail by updated server

Tags: php, email, server, smtp, phpmailer

i have problem in this code that not show any error but it's not send mail 
actuality my server is update and that is now working, before updating server it's working fine, i don't know that it reason please help me
Thank you

```
$config['useragent']        = 'PHPMailer';
$config['protocol']         = 'mail'; 
$config['mailpath']         = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host']        = 'localhost';
$config['smtp_user']        = 'email@mail.com';
$config['smtp_pass']        = '********';
$config['smtp_port']        = 25;
$config['smtp_timeout']     = 30;                       // (in seconds)
$config['smtp_crypto']      = 'ssl';                       // '' or 'tls' or 'ssl'
$config['smtp_debug']       = 0;                        // PHPMailer's SMTP debug info level: 0 = off, 1 = commands, 2 = commands and data, 3 = as 2 plus connection status, 4 = low level data output.
$config['debug_output']     = '';                       // PHPMailer's SMTP debug output: 'html', 'echo', 'error_log' or user defined function with parameter $str and $level. NULL or '' means 'echo' on CLI, 'html' otherwise.
$config['smtp_auto_tls']    = true;                     // Whether to enable TLS encryption automatically if a server supports it, even if `smtp_crypto` is not set to 'tls'.
$config['smtp_conn_options'] = array();                 // SMTP connection options, an array passed to the function stream_context_create() when connecting via SMTP.
$config['wordwrap']         = true;
$config['wrapchars']        = 76;
$config['mailtype']         = 'html';                   // 'text' or 'html'
$config['charset']          = null;                     // 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15', ...; NULL (preferable) means config_item('charset'), i.e. the character set of the site.
$config['validate']         = true;
$config['priority']         = 3;                        // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5; on PHPMailer useragent NULL is a possible option, it means that X-priority header is not set at all, see https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/449
$config['crlf']             = "\n";                     // "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r"
$config['newline']          = "\n";                     // "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r"
$config['bcc_batch_mode']   = false;
$config['bcc_batch_size']   = 200;
$config['encoding']         = '8bit';                  
$config['dkim_domain']      = '';                       // DKIM signing domain name, for exmple 'example.com'.
$config['dkim_private']     = '';                       // DKIM private key, set as a file path.
$config['dkim_private_string'] = '';                    // DKIM private key, set directly from a string.
$config['dkim_selector']    = '';                       // DKIM selector.
$config['dkim_passphrase']  = '';                       // DKIM passphrase, used if your key is encrypted.
$config['dkim_identity']    = '';                       // DKIM
```

and this is my mail function in controller

```
 $this->load->library('email');

 $subject = 'This is a test';
 $message = '<p> testing message.</p>';
 $body = '<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>' . $message . ' </body> </html>';
 $result = $this->email
->from('email@mail.com')
->reply_to('email@mail.com') 
->to('senfmail@mail.com')
->subject($subject)
->message($body)
->send();

var_dump($result);
echo '<br />';
echo $this->email->print_debugger();

exit;
```

Comment: Did the paths and used ports remain the same, after the server was updated?

Comment: yes that's have same paths and port but it's php version updated on 7.0

Comment: If you updated from a PHP version older than 5.6, your problem is likely certificate verification.

Comment: yes it's verification problem. thanks